# Creating a custom menu in .NET WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menu

Using .NET 2.0 with WinForms, I'd like to create a custom, multi-columned menu (similiar to the word 2007 look&feel, but without the ribbon).

My approach was creating a control, and using a left/right docked toolstrip, I have constructed a similar look&feel of a menu. However, there are a few shortcomings of this solution, such as

- the control can only be placed, and displayed within the form;
- if the form is too small, some area of the control won't be displayed;
- the control also have to be manually shown/hidden.

Thus, I'm looking for a way to display this control outside of the boundaries of the application. Creating a new form would result in title-bar deactivating on display, so that's also out. Alternatively, any other approach to create a customized menu would be very welcomed.

Edit: I don't want to use any commercial products for this; and since it's about a simple menu customization, it's not related to Microsoft's ribbon "research" in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MenuStrip class has a Renderer property.  You can assign your own ToolStripRenderer derived class to customize the painting.  It's a fair amount of work.

Answer (score 2):

- unless you are in the business of providing .net components, you should be looking to buy it off the shelf. Its a lot of work getting such a control right - There are already vendors providing this kind of UI. e.g. [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/RibbonWinForms/)
- if you are trying to build this component as a product, you should look at the link below. Apparently Microsoft has a 'royalty-free' license around the Office UI to protect their R&D investments. As of now you need to tell them that you are using something similar to the Office UI. [More of that here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx)